# Values out of select box when it filling with javascript

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, frontend

Hi I'm making a user interface like this:

[image]

I have a select box that is fill dynamically with values of my database but when I fill it the values ​​get out of it self like can see in the picture

when I put the values as following form

```
<select class="form-control pool">
 <option value="value">Values</option>
</select>
```

I don't have the same problem. I'm using bootstrap-select plugin I make this with Jquery

```
  $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("getPools", "MakeRequest")",
                type: 'post',
                datatype: 'application/json',
                data: {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $('.pool').append('<option value="' + data[i]["idPool"] + '" >' + data[i] 
                        ["idPool"] + " | " + data[i]["poolDescription"] + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
                    $('select').selectpicker();

        });
```

If I use refresh this happening:

[image]

Now I have select values but the values continue get out of select box

What is the correct form to fill it?

Comment: `.selectpicker('refresh')` https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/

Comment: I tried using refresh method. and this fix one problem, now I can select the values.
But the values are drawing get out of my select

Comment: Looks like you're missing a css include